# Нужно ускорить поиск палиндрома

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа проверяет, является ли число палиндромом, и если нет, то подбирает ближайший палиндром, больший начального числа.
Чувствую себя идиотом, что делаю это перебором, но иначе мне было не придумать.

```
num = str(input())
end=False
while end is False:
    if num == num[::-1]:
      print(f'{num}')
      end = True
    else:
      num = str(int(num)+1)
      print(num)
      end = False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мой ответ не далеко ушел от [ответа MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1358711/416121).

Делим строку на три части: лево, середина, право. Середина может быть пустой.
Первый кандидат строится как конкатенация "лево", "середина", задом_наперед("лево"). Если он больше чем исходное число либо равен ему, задача решена.

Если нет, то добавляем единицу к конкатенации ("лево", "середина") и из неё строим новый палиндром.

```
s = input()                              # '12345'
n = int(s)                               # 12345

half = len(s) // 2                       # 2
left = s[:half]                          # '12'
mid = s[half:len(s) - half]              # '3'

m = int(left + mid + left[::-1])         # int('12' + '3' + '21')
if m < n:                                
    left_mid = str(int(left + mid) + 1)  # str(int('12' + '3') + 1)
    left = left_mid[:half]               # '12'
    m = int(left_mid + left[::-1])       # int('124' + '21')

print(m)
```

> ```
> $ echo 1 | python next_palindrome.py 
> 1
>
> $ echo 1234 | python next_palindrome.py 
> 1331
>
> $ echo 4321 | python next_palindrome.py 
> 4334
>
> $ echo 12345 | python next_palindrome.py 
> 12421
>
> $ echo 54321 | python next_palindrome.py 
> 54345
>
> $ echo 12943 | python next_palindrome.py 
> 13031
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Давайте попробуем так:

Выделяем первую половину и вторую половину, перевёртываем вторую.

Если первая половина больше, то делаем вторую равной перевёрнутой первой .

Иначе увеличиваем первую половину (вместе со средней цифрой для нечётной длины) на единицу, делаем вторую равной перевёрнутой первой (без средней цифры)

Answer (score 2):

```
number = input()

if number == number[::-1]:
    print(number)
else:
    delta = 1 if len(number) % 2 else 0
    central_number = number[len(number)//2] if delta else ''
    first_part = number[:len(number)//2]
    second_part = first_part[::-1]
    number = first_part + central_number + second_part
    print(number)
```

нет смысла оборачивать input в str, так как input и без того возвращает str-object, а вот мое решение без всякого перебора

Comment: `1234` -> `1221`. Второй меньше первого.

Comment: Числа в некоторых случаях получаются меньше. Палиндром составляется, насколько мои навыки чтения кода говорят, грубо говоря просто переставляя начало в конец.

Answer (score 0):

по рецепту [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1358711/457260):

```
n = input('> ')
l = len(n)//2
a, b, c = n[:l], n[l:-l], n[-l:]

if a and int(a[::-1]) < int(c):  
    a = str(int(a)+(b=='9')) if b else str(int(a)+1)
    b = str((int(b)+1)%10) if b else ''
c = a[::-1] if a else c
    
p = a + b + c
print(f'{p = }')
```

**UPD**

Спасибо @StanislavVolodarskiy за замеченную ошибку в коде из-за которой неправильно обрабатывались числа с 9 в середине и однозначные числа. Теперь все вроде работает как надо, но код стал довольно корявым))

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, над этим кодом надо еще поработать, удаляю.