# Наименьший палиндром, больший данного числа

Tags: python-3.x

Требуется написать программу на Python-3, принимающую на входе целое число и выводящую наименьшее целое число, являющееся десятичным палиндромом и превышающее полученное на входе число. Например, если на входе получено число 310610407, программа выдаст: 310616013.

Я вначале написал с ошибкой:

```
k=int(input())
while(str(k)!=str(k)[::-1]):
    k+=1
print(k)
```

Дело в том, что написанная программа работает во всех случаях (если число на входе не является отрицательным), кроме одного, а именно когда число на входе уже является палиндромом. К примеру, если ввести 999999, то на выходе его же и получим.

Можно поправить положение следующим образом:

```
k=int(input())
if str(k)==str(k)[::-1]:
    k+=1
while(str(k)!=str(k)[::-1]):
    k+=1
print(k)
```

Но нет ли более элегантного способа, чтобы не добавлять «‎if»?

Кстати, а как быть с отрицательными числами? По идее, если на входе получено, например, -310610407, программа должна выдать не -310616013, а -310606013. Как вообще работать с минусом? Программа воспринимает его как элемент строки, то есть, с точки зрения программы, если прочесть, скажем, число -310610407 справа налево, получится 704016013-. Как исправить сложившуюся ситуацию?

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужно ускорить поиск палиндрома](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1358706/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Comment: Если считать знак минус частью палиндрома, то отрицательных палиндромов нет = надо возвращать ноль. Если минус не переставляем, то надо искать ближайший меньший по абсолютной величине палиндром. Задача от этого не выиграла.